# How to go about inserting domain objects in db at start of API

Tags: java, rest, jersey, solid-principles, clean-architecture

Im building a REST API in java with jersey and jetty. I have a complex domain in which I have a class (Workers). I want to be able to dynamically add workers through a POST. However, the business logic requires me to have a few default workers with fixed values. So at the start of the API, I need to add them to my db (right now its in memory). In terms of clean code whats the best way to go about that?

I thought about initializing my repository with these defaults workers, but I feel like its violating the SRP for the WorkerRepo class, I feel like that should be the job of the application layer as its specific to this application, not to the domain if that makes sense. Where should I move the logic for this initialization? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of thinking, I moved the setup in the **application layer**, where I actually instanciate all my dependencies (in a class named ApplicationContext).

I created an interface **WorkerContext** and created a concrete implementation WorkerContextX where X = NAMEOFTHEAPP. This context class contains all the default values and uses the injected repo to add these default values to the repo. So at the startup of the API, in the **ApplicationContext** class, I call the WorkerContext method that setup my workerRepo.

This way, I can easily change the setup strategy in the blink of an eye and it doesnt violate the SRP anymore in the repo. And I now respect the DIP as the repo(which was in the domain) doesnt rely on things that are dictated by the application layer.

I posted this as I thought it was a decent solution and could help other people, feel free to critique or improve this solution.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective I would design your needs just as I would design all other use cases. E.g. a `SetupWorkerInteractor`.

I would use an `ApplicationRunner` that encapsulated the application startup logic. E.g. parse the command line args, build the application context, call the initialization process and run the application. Of cource I would also separate these aspects into different classes, but I guess you get the picture of what I mean.

In my case I would use the `ApplicationLog` as the "presenter" of the setup use case's output.

For simplicity I omitted the entity and request/response models.

[image: SetupWorkerInteractor]

If I do it this way, it doesn't matter if the `SetupWorkerInputBoundary` is called from the `ApplicationRunner`, a `RestService` or e.g. a messaging system. I can also test the setup just like any other use case.